# lightswitch create lookup list

Tags: sql-server-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've created a simple contact database with three tables, `Corporate`, `Contact`, and `Country`.  I've created a LightSwitch application on top of it and am trying to create a countrycode lookup.  i.e. on the new Corporate screen, for *countrycode* field have a lookup list coming from the country table.

How can I do this?  If I was writing a SQL query it would purely be:

```
SELECT CountryCode 
FROM Country
```

In the query designer it makes you create filters, I don't want to add any filters!  Also, I've created foreign keys, unique key constraints but LightSwitch doesn't seem to recognise them and complained when I was importing my tables?

*** UPDATE ***

Error below

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Easy way? Create a view in your DB and import it. Less easy way? Create a sub-query of `Country` in its properties set the *summary* field to `CountryCode' and ad the query as a list in your screen. It will then only display the CountryCodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, if relationships are set up correctly, this would just happen for you automatically. LightSwitch is very good at this actually.

If I understand correctly, your data source is an *external SQL database*, that you've added into your LightSwitch application as an *attached data source*. If there was a relationship between the *Client* table & the *Country* table, then LightSwitch would create the look-up combo box in the *Client* screen **automatically**. But it's not enough to just have a foreign key column, you have to create a **relationship** between the two tables.

You don't mention what the columns are in your tables, or more importantly the column **data types** are. The *Country* table should have an **integer primary key**, plus a text column for the name. In the *Client* table, it should also have an **integer primary key**, plus an **integer foreign key**. The relationship should be created in the *Client* table between its *Country* foreign key column and the *Country* table's primary key column.

You mentioned that LightSwitch "complained" when you were importing your tables. What was the error message?

Comment: so the problem i'm having is in my corporate table i have an ID column (int Primary Key), and then CorporateID (from another system) int which is set to Unique Key. In the Contacts table I have ContactID (int Primary Key) and again, CorporateID. There is a foreign key relationship between CorporateID in the two tables. Lightswitch doesn't seem to be able to deal with this scenario, or i'm not aware of a way of making it work... i'll attach image of what i'm getting above.

Comment: You have two issues here. First is the fact that LightSwitch is rejecting your relationships. You haven't mentioned it, but my guess would be you're actually using a composite primary key (a key composed of more than one column)?

Comment: Then, when you have that sorted issue out, you'll need to create a modeled query (very easy to do), based on the Country table, where you can then filter on the CorporateID for your CountryCodes, without affecting anything else that uses the Country table. After you get the primary keys sorted (if indeed you can), have a look at http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/lightswitch-nested-autocompletebox-for-data-entry/